# Updating one item from multiple nested list python

Tags: python

I have a list of multiple lists and I need to be able to update the maximum value from all of its occurrences so that it is changed to 0. For example, for this list I want to update the maximum which is 6 to 0. But 6 is in two positions both in different lists. So how could I update both of them at the same time?

```
g.graph = [[0, 2, 0, 6, 0],
           [2, 0, 3, 0, 5],
           [0, 3, 0, 0, 0],
           [6, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 5, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

This does what you ask, but it depends on what you mean by 'delete':

```
graph = [[0, 2, 0, 6, 0],
         [2, 0, 3, 0, 5],
         [0, 3, 0, 0, 0],
         [6, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 5, 0, 0, 0]]


def del_max(g):
    m = max(max(row) for row in g)
    return [[x if x != m else None for x in xs] for xs in g]


print(del_max(graph))
```

You can't know what the maximum is beforehand, so the function finds the max of all rows and then returns the input array with only the values that are not the max.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I accidentally wrote my questions incorrectly. I am actually trying to update the max value to equal 0.

Comment: Should be trivial to adjust the example I wrote then - change `None` to `0`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you got to know what is the maximum value from these lists, then you can delete all of its occurrences.

This code can solve your problem:

```
graph = [[0, 2, 0, 6, 0],
        [2, 0, 3, 0, 5],
        [0, 3, 0, 0, 0],
        [6, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 5, 0, 0, 0]]

max_val = 0

for lst in graph:
    for item in lst:
        if item > max_val:
            max_val = item

for lst in graph:
    for item in lst:
        if item == max_val:
            lst.remove(item)

print(str(graph))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I accidentally wrote my questions incorrectly. I am actually trying to update the max value to equal 0.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this as follows:

```
def update(list_, value):
    try:
        index = list_.index(value)
        list_.[index] = 0
    except ValueError:
        pass

value_to_update = max([i for l in g.graph for i in l])    # Flattening the g.graph list to find the maximum value
list(map(lambda x: update(x, value_to_update), g.graph))    # Calling list() because it needs to run over the map, which is lazy
```

This codes actually updates the values from the original `g.graph` list, instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I accidentally wrote my questions incorrectly. I am actually trying to update the max value to equal 0.

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another way if you are interested to use `itertools.chain` to flatten the list and get max value

```
from itertools import chain
[[0 if j == max(chain(*graph)) else j for j in i] for i in graph]
```

Output:

```
[[0, 2, 0, 0, 0],
 [2, 0, 3, 0, 5],
 [0, 3, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 5, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I accidentally wrote my questions incorrectly. I am actually trying to update the max value to equal 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use remove method.
    list.remove(x)
```

Where list is a name of your list, x is what needs to be removed from it.